# Troubles with my Firebase-integration inside my Vue.js App

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

Currently I'm trying to implement firebase into my Vue.js App. I set up Vue.js using the Vue CLI, installed firebase as well as vuefire and bootstrap-vue, now I tried to get some data I inserted into my db manually but somehow I don't get any data from firebase. I'm quite new to Vue.js so this might be a beginners error but I don't really know what to do right now.

I don't know if it matters but I plan on using vuex later on, so I installed that as well, I've followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4deVCNJq3qc&t=1h50m36s) on how to set up Vue.js, in there she is using a local js file as a database, I got it all set up but now I want to use Firebase as my database.

I think it would be a bit to much if I post every file thats relevant for this in here so I created a [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Brecherchef/vuefirebase) with all the files, but here is the part where I think the problem might be:

```html
<b-table striped hover :items="clients"></b-table>
{{ clients }}
```

```js
import { db } from '@/environment/firebase'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      clients: [],
      systems: []
    }
  },
  firestore: {
    clients: db.collection('clients'),
    systems: db.collection('systems')
  }
}
```

somehow Vue.js doesn't pull the data correctly. I thought this might have something to do with an authentication error from firebase but my console doesn't show any errors neither does my console where I'm running the `npm run serve` and at this point I don't really know what to do anymore.

It's also possibly that my error is in my inegrationfile of firebase since I just copied the one from the [Get started page from vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/getting-started.html#installation):

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'

// Get a Firestore instance
export const db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()

// Export types that exists in Firestore
// This is not always necessary, but it's used in other examples
const { TimeStamp, GeoPoint } = firebase.firestore
export { TimeStamp, GeoPoint }
```

But, as I said, I don't really know what my error is here since from my understanding everything should work up to this point..

Answer (score 1):

In your `main.js` you included twice:

`import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'`

without including the `vuefire.js` plugin file.